# No files detected on FTP server

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, directory, ftp-client

I'm running a FTP server, which contains a file in the root directory: "/".
My program is able to connect and login to the server and it is able change to the root directory. But when I try to list the name of the files and print out the single file located, it gives me an error saying: "Attempt to read from a null array". Here is my code:

```
    ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    Log.d("LoginActivity", "FTP");
    ftpClient.connect("xxx.xxx.x.xx", xx);
    boolean connected = ftpClient.isConnected();
    if(connected){
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "connected: true");
    }
    boolean loggedIn = ftpClient.login("Name", "PassWord");
    if(loggedIn){
    Log.d("LoginActivity", "loggedIn: true");
    }
    boolean foundDirectory = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/");
    if(foundDirectory){
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "directory found: true");
    }
    String[] files = ftpClient.listNames("/");
    Log.d("LoginActivity", files[0]);
```

How come no files are found, when I certainly know there is one located in my rootdirectory?

Comment: 'and it is able change to the root directory'. Ok. What was the directory it landed in? Use printCurrentWorkingDirectory().

Comment: It prints out "/" as expected. But I already found a solution. I ran my program with the emulator. Today I tried the exact same thing with a real device and for some reason it works.